# How to resolve error: "Missing required Boost components >= vX.XX, please install/upgrade Boost or configure your search paths"

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to install [gtsam](https://collab.cc.gatech.edu/borg/gtsam/) and am running into some problems.

I installed boost to `c:/program files/boost/boost_1_56_0` and added the following to my CMakeLists.text:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "c:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_56_0")

set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib")
```

However, I am getting the following error whenever I try to configure CMake:

```
-- GTSAM_SOURCE_ROOT_DIR: [C:/Program Files/gtsam-3.1.0]

-- Could NOT find Boost

-- CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:106 (message):
   Missing required Boost components >= v1.43, please install/upgrade Boost or
   configure your search paths.
```

I am completely new to this and am at my wits end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the boost directory:

```
include_directories(${BOOST_DIRECTORY})
```

then you need to use the boost header files for your executable:

```
set(HEADER_FILES ${BOOST_DIRECTORY}/file1.hpp ${BOOST_DIRECTORY}/file2.hpp)
add_executable(myexec execfile.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
```

Comment: What do you mean use the boost header files for several targets?